# NodeJS: debugging memory use

Tags: node.js

I've got a web crawler that is eating up a bunch of memory. I've tried `node --trace-gc` as posted in "NodeJS 0.3.1 app leaking memory" and the problem is similar. I am using the async lib for multiple gets to the server.

Can someone point me in the right direction to find the leak? Any good tools or methods that i could use?

Comment: Looks like jsdom has a memory leak...

http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/ea7f8e9c215962c9/73c1933e8073afc3?pli=1

I was using the wonderful jquery lib for my crawler which depends on jsdom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try node-inspector which would allow you to use WebKit's WebInspector.

Get it via npm `npm install node-inspector`

Comment: This is fantastic! It does show global/local/context.

What's really cool is that you can do breakpoints.

Comment: Looks like jsdom has a memory leak...

http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/ea7f8e9c215962c9/73c1933e8073afc3?pli=1

I was using the wonderful jquery lib for my crawler which depends on jsdom.

Comment: You can also take heap snapshots via node-inspector if you require('v8-profiler') somewhere in your code. See the readme for more information: https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector